# Connect to on-premise SQL database with Azure Logic apps without data gateway?

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps, gateway

I was looking into connecting to my local SQL database on my computer with azure logic apps, and was reading about it when i suddenly noticed i needed something called "on-premises data gateway" to be installed.

So i looked at the System requirements and to my surprise the recommended requirements where:

8 Core CPU
8 GB Memory
64-bit version of Windows 2012 R2 (or later)

and minimum:

.NET 4.5 Framework
64-bit version of Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 (or later).

So i was thinking is there any other way for people who have a "normal" laptop computer to get this done or do i really have top have a mastodont of a computer to make this happen?

worth to mention here is i only want to be able to connect to a local SQL server for testing and training purposes.

Comment: As long as you meet the minimum requirements you should be good to go. The recommended requirements are for production configurations.

Comment: Ok good to know, thank you :)

Comment: @SzymonWylezol Why not make your response an actual answer and then John can upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you meet the minimum requirements you should be good to go. The recommended requirements are for production configurations.